# Servlet file download using thread

Tags: multithreading, servlets, download

I am facing a problem in the download servlet to download files.

I got the output stream from httpResponse.getOutputStream()
and passed this output stream object to another class - FileOperations.
This FileOperations is invoked as a new thread. When I write the file to the output stream and flush it, the file is popped up for saving it correctly,
but on saving and opening the file, I see the first lines as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2012 14:19:37 GMT
2000
```

After this the file content is written and after a few lines, again '2000' is written and likewise.

Please let me know what can be done to run the downloads in threaded mode.

I tried downloading a file without calling the thread and it got properly downloaded.
I passed FileOutputStream instead of the ServletOutputStream to the thread and it also downloaded properly.

Comment: It appears the HTTP responses for the new thread are ending up in your file. You say: "I passed FileOutputStream instead of the ServletOutputStream to the thread and it also downloaded properly." -- why is this not a satisfactory answer to your problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the HTTP response outside the current HTTP request thread from the servlet method. When the servlet method returns (while the thread still runs in background), the container will namely immediately send the response.

Downloading won't go faster if you delegate to a other thread. The current HTTP request is already processed by a dedicated thread. I'd suggest to forget this approach and just perform the streaming job in the current HTTP request thread. This saves your application from creating unnecessary threads which would only cost more resources.

To improve downloading speed, your servlet can better be redesigned to support [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) requests. This way the client can by itself either automatically or using some specific browser plugin send multiple [`If-Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.27) requests to download the file in pieces which will then physically use multiple HTTP connections (and thus multiple HTTP requests/threads in the server side). This is all however not exactly trivial. You can find a concrete kickoff example of such a servlet in [this blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html). Note that while this approach might theoretically improve the download speed, you're still bordered by the network bandwitdh limits. It's only faster if the incoming network bandwidth of the client is broader than the outcoming one of the server and the server (or the ISP!) is been configured to limit the bandwidth on a per-connection basis. This was during the 90's not uncommon, but these days it's not so common.